# Dividing a StringBuffer into smaller parts

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I have a large stringbuffer which i would like to break into smaller parts. The string buffer looks like this

```
"name1+name2+name3+name4+..........+name2000"
```

Where

```
name1=john
name2=prince 
and so on.
```

(You get the idea.name1,name2,name3 stand for actual names of varying length)

Now i would like to store the names in a string array with each positon containing a  200 names.

```
string[0]="name1+name2+name3+........+name200";
string[1]="name201+name202+...."
```

How would i go about achieving this task?

Comment: Are the names in the `StringBuffer` separated by a `,`??

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What part of your attempted solution is specifically giving you trouble?

Comment: I'm curious. How did the data get into the StringBuffer that way in the first place, and why do you want to split it up into array elements with 200 names per element? Surely what you really want is just a list of names, most probably the same list that you started with before you got anywhere near the StringBuffer. Sounds like taking several hammers to crack a nut to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(<StringBufferObject>);
int count = 0;
int arrCount = 0;
StringBuffer temp;
String[] stringArr = new String[x];
while(str.hasMoreTokens()) {
    count++;
    if(count != 200) {
        temp.append(str.nextToken());
    }
    else {
    stringArr[arrCount] = temp;
    temp.delete(0,temp.length());
    count = 0;
    arrCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot easier to split a String using String.split() if that's possible:

```
/* something like this */

String arrayOfStrings = inputString.split("\+");
```

If you have to keep it as a StringBuffer you'll have to loop over the input and tokenize it yourself.

I guess it would look something like this:

```
public String[] getTwoHundredStrings(StringBuffer inputBuff, String someToken)
{
    String [] nameArray = new String [200];

    int currentPos = 0;
    int nextPos = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 200; i ++ ) {

        nextPos = inputBuff.indexOf(someToken, currentPos);

        if ( nextPos < 0 ) {
            break;
        }

        String nextName = inputBuff.substring(currentPos, nextPos);

        nameArray[i] = nextName;        
        currentPos = nextPos;
    }   

    /* do some cleanup if nameArray has less than 200 elements */

    return nameArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have some delimiter between each name. To break the string we should have some delimiter.
If you have delimiter you can use subString() in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
String[] tempNames = new String(namesBuffer).split("+");
```

and then

```
int length = (tempNames.length / 200)+ (tempName.length % 200)
String[] names = new String[length];
for(int i = 0 ; i< tempNames.length ; i++){
   for(int j = 0 ; j < length ; j++)
       names[j] = tempNames[i];
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Why `names[j] = tempNames[i]`? He needs to store smaller chunks of data into the names String array, something like `names[0] = tempNames[0] + "+" + tempNames[1] + ... + tempNames[199];` while you are overriding names[j] (names[0], names[1]...) for every `i` iteration.

Comment: ya you are right I had to but the internal for loop out and vise versa

Answer (score 0):

1. Split on "+", using `String.split("\\+")`
2. Get chucks, in smaller arrays, [`Arrays.copyOfRange(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28boolean%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29)
3. Join using [Guava Joiner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) like `Joiner.on("+").join(smallerArray)`